# Number of occurrences in contiguous subarrays

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How to count the number of occurrences of each element in all contiguous subarrays?

For an array $[1,2,3]$, the contiguous subarrays are:

- $[1]$, $[2]$, $[3]$
- $[1,2]$, $[2,3]$
- $[1,2,3]$

$1$ occurs *$3$ times*, $2$ occurs *$4$ times* and $3$ occurs *$3$ times*.

Comment: can the array contain repeated elements? Do you want an algorithm? What is the complexity you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Different elements. O(1).

Comment: You mean $\mathcal O(1)$ for a specific element right?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo I am expecting the answer to be related for all elements. But if it's not yeah, O(1) per element.

Comment: Is it related to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1940236/how-to-compute-a-function-on-every-composition-of-n)?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes, same question, but I hadn't seen that question.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I arrived at the same result you did $u(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=k}^n (j-i+1) 2^{\max(0,i-2)+\max(0,n-j-1)}$, but I could not boil it down to $O(n)$ :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that our array is: $[1,2,3\dots ,n]$.
How many contiguous subarrays contain $k$? Look at the following drawing:

$|1|2|3|4|\dots |k-1|k|k+1|\dots |n|$.

Every subarray containing $k$ can be obtained by selecting a "barrier" to the left of $k$ and a barrier to the right of $k$. There are $k$ barriers to the left of $k$ and $n-k+1$ barriers to the right of $k$.

Therefore there are $k(n-k+1)$ contiguous subarrays containing $k$ in the array $[1,2,3\dots n]$

Comment: Thanks! I found another way to arrive at the result, though yours is much concise!

Comment: @prakharsingh95 you're welcome, happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You grouped the continguous subarrays by length already: this is quite useful!

For example, if we take the array [1,2,3,4]:

- [1], [2], [3], [4] (all numbers occur once)
- [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4] (1 and 4 occur once, 2 and 3 occur twice)
- [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4] (1 and 4 occur once, 2 and 3 occur twice)
- [1, 2, 3, 4] (all numbers occur once)

There are a lot of things to notice here, of which I will state a couple:

- 1 and 4 have the same number of occurences, just like 2 and 3.
- 1 and 4 (more generally, 1 and $n$) occur exactly once in the continguous subarrays of a certain length.
- 2 and 3 occur once, then twice, twice again, then once again.

Try this yourself for [1,2,3,4,5]. Do you notice anything? Can you generalise this?

Comment: That line "once twice, twice, once again' was most helpful. Arrived at @JorgeFernándezHidalgo answer

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @JorgeFernándezHidalgo answer, here's another way to arrive at the result, (thanks @HarrySmit for helping out):

All the results for subarrays of size till $N/2$ are duplicated in subarrays of greater size ($[1,2,3,4]$ has the same elements as $[1]$,$[2]$,$[3]$,$[4]$, subarrys of size $2$ contain the same elements as subarrays of size $N-1$ and so on).

Also note that an element at index $k$ occurs $n$ times in subarrays of length $1$ to $n$, and $k$ times in bigger subarrays (till length $N/2$).

So the total number of occurrences in all subarrays upto length $N/2$ is $1+2+...+k + (N/2-k)*k = k(N-k+1)/2$.

This result is replicated in subarrays of length greater than $N/2$, so we multiply by $2$, the final result being $k(N-k+1)$.